# Using admin to run periodic tasks in the djcelery section of the database

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, periodic-task

It seems that django admin has all the tools for assigning periodic tasks to intervals.  Yet, I can't find any instructions on how to get periodic tasks to work in this module.
How do you configure celery to configure periodic tasks in django admin?